# when one click works and the other not

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I got the problem that i got 2 ng-clicks but only one works. when I reload the page always only one button works the other not. for this i use angularjs, HTML and Css.
the first click:

```
<img class="cClickable" ng-click="addPassword()" src="plus.svg">
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.addPassword = function() {
   var newPassword = {
                Id: null,
                Name: '',
                Passwort: '', 
                Beschreibung: '',
                Category: []
            }
            $scope.editPassword(newPassword);
            $scope.titlePopup = "Neues Passwort hinzufügen";
        }


$scope.editPassword = function(password) {
     $scope.currentPassword = angular.copy(password);
     $scope.isShownEdit = true;
     $scope.titlePopup = "Passwort bearbeiten";
}
```

the second button:

```
<img class="cClickable cTableImgedit" ng-click="editPassword(item)" src="pencil.svg">
```

when i click the button a popup is in the front.

the images are existing.

this is the popup.

```
<div class="backgroundOverlay cShow" ng-show="isShownEdit">
    <div class="dropDown positionPopUp inpuBlock" id="add">
        <div class="inputBlock">
            <h1 class="popupTitle">{{titlePopup}}</h1>
            <div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="Name" ng-model="currentPassword.Name">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="Passwort" ng-model="currentPassword.Passwort">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="Beschreibung" ng-model="currentPassword.Beschreibung">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <div class="divSmall">
                        <label class="inputDropdownPlaceholder">Kategorien</label>
                        <div class="divOptions" ng-repeat="item in categories">
                            <label class="labelDropDown"><input type="checkbox" class="inputDropDown" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-checked="checkedCategory(item)" ng-init="item.isChecked = checkedCategory(item)" ng-change="changedCategory(item)">{{item.Label}}</label><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cClearFloat cButtons">
                        <button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="showAlertPassword()">Speichern</button>
                        <button class="cButtonAbbrechen" ng-click="isShownEdit= false">Abbrechen</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click on the images the popup comes into the front.

Comment: Check if the pencil.svg exists

Comment: what does that argument `item` holds?

Comment: item are data for the list i got. the second button is in a list.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" ? and wich one is "not working" ?

Comment: If the second is rendered in the list, you probably need to reference the parent scope do access the `editPassword` function. Try to add some `console.log` in that function to see if this function is called or not.

Comment: when i click one button its working, but when i want to click the other button its not working. I need to refresh the site to can click the second button but then the first button is not working. always only one button works.

Comment: could you provide more HTML code? and btw you should use "ng-src" instead of "src"

Comment: Is the ng-click called ? if you alert() inside editPassword() does it show the alert ?

Comment: yes when i click the button i see the alert.

Comment: maybe you have some issue with eventHandlers?

Comment: When you click both button ? the addPassword and edit password the popup shows ?

Comment: when i'm on the page and i want to add a password its working. Now i want to edit a password it's not working but it's working when i refresh the side.

Comment: after i edited the hole code all was working but i cant change it back because i need the new things.

Comment: When you add password the "popop" is shown then you close de popup and click de edit password ? and the popup is not showing ?

Comment: its not showing but when i refresh the side i can click edit password and this popup is shown but than the popup from addpassword its not showing.

Comment: You have to provide all the code with both popup. I dont see any addPassword popup

Comment: I will try to  makea snippet..

Comment: So I tried your code and have put it in a fiddle, but it works perfectly fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6542/

Comment: Your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/CHVbb/1429/

Comment: @all i found the error. I got the problem when i save the data from the popup i can open the popup from the other button. But when i cancel it it's not working.